# How do I assert a 'specific' element attribute value with Selenium IDE?

Tags: attributes, element, assert, selenium-ide, verify

**Problem:** I can't figure out how to assert an captured value (Store Attribute) to the expected value.

**What I'm trying to do:** I'm still learning Selenium IDE. I figured out how to use Store Attribute to capture an Elements Style attribute and can Echo the variable to make sure I did indeed capture it. Now I want to compare (verify or assert) the value in the captured variable is equal to the expected value.

**What I have tried:** I've tried Assert Text, Assert Value, and have targetted the element attribute directly in the same way I captured it, then using the Value field for the expected value (like you would do asserting an "invalid" message. That seems to fail though. I've targeted the variable ${highligh} in the same way and it failed as well. So I'm not sure exactly how to verify/assert an attribute value.

In the images below, I've also tried Assert Text on the first and Assert Value on the second with Targets and Values remaining the same I just didn't capture the images.

[image: Attribute-Call]

[image: Attribute-Variable]

Answer (score 1):

After looking further for an answer here (StackOverflow) and elsewhere, just using the `assert` command as follows worked for me:

`assert` | `<variable>` (w/o ${}) | `<expected-value>`

[image: answer]